# "Expected ',' instead of ' ' " message for a Response of Spring Boot POST Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, fasterxml

I am trying to build an application to generate a scoreboard for a sport using Spring Boot. Following are my Entities :

```java
    @XmlRootElement (name = "Player")
    public class Player{
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;
       @XmlElement(required = true)
       private Team team;

       //All the constructors and getter setter

    }
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Team{
      private String name;
      @XmlElement(required=true)
      private List<Player> players;
      //All the constructor and getter setter
    }
```

Following are the controllers

`Player Controller:`

```java
    @RestController
    public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    PlayerService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/players")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<Player>> getAllPlayers(){
        List<Player> players = service.getAllPlayers();

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        List<MediaType> medias = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        medias.add(MediaType.ALL);

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Player>>(players, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ="/player/{team}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Player> addPlayer(@RequestBody Player player, @PathVariable("team") String teamName){
        System.out.println("Inside PlayerController: "+player.getLastName());
        Player p = service.addPlayer(player, teamName);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        List<MediaType> medias = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        medias.add(MediaType.ALL);
        responseHeaders.setAccept(medias);

        return new ResponseEntity<Player>(p, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    }
```

`Team Controller:`

```java
    @RestController
    public class TeamController {

    @Autowired
    private TeamService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/teams")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<Team>> getAllTeams(){
        List<Team> teams = service.getAllTeams();
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        List<MediaType> medias = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        medias.add(MediaType.ALL);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Team>>(teams, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "team/{name}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Team> getOneTeamByName(@PathVariable String name){
        Team t = service.getOneTeamByName(name);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        List<MediaType> medias = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        medias.add(MediaType.ALL);
        return new ResponseEntity<Team>(t, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);


    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/team")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Team> addTeam(@RequestBody Team team){
        System.out.println("New team name : "+team.getName());
        Team t = service.addTeam(team);

        return new ResponseEntity<Team>(t, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    }
```

I am testing the REST API using Postman app. I initiate the team post the following JSON data on `"http://localhost:8090/team"`:

```
    {"name" : "TeamA"}
```

Now, when I post a player with following JSON on URL `http://localhost:8090/player/TeamA`

```
    {"firstName" : "TeamA", "lastName" : "Player1"}
```

The response I see on Postman is wierd. On selecting JSON it says:
`Expected ',' instead of ''`
On Selecting Text, the response is:

```
    {"id":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"team":{"name":"TeamA","players":[{"id":null,"firstName":"TeamA","lastName":"Player1","team":{"name":"TeamA","players":[{"id":null,"firstName":"TeamA","lastName":"Player1","team":{"name":"TeamA"......
```

Is there any way in which I can get a response in proper format. For example I am expecting the JSON Response like:

```
    {"id":"1", "firstName":"TeamA", "lastName":"Player1" 
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm new to spring and I recently faced a similar issue. for me, it happened due to infinite recursion between two entities and I solved using **JsonManagedReference**, **JsonBackReference**.See if your issue can be solved this way.

Comment: @KalyanRam Appreciate your inputs! So, It tried annotating Team instance in Player Class with 'JsonMangedReference' as follows :                        and player list in Team class with 'JsonBackReference' I face this exception : back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.scorecard.entity.Player)

Comment: try changing Player(JsonBackReference) and Team(JsonMangedReference) it may work.

Answer (score 3):

This is very old post but I faced similar issue where back reference application was going in loop and I was getting similar kind of error. I wanted dependent object to be included in to be retained on either side of the entity. `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonIdentityInfo` were not helping. You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` instead.

In class `Team`

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"team"})
private List<Player> players;
```

and in `Player`

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"players"})
private Team team;
```

This way worked for me very well. This post http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html?m=1 explains pros and cons of each of the above annotations.